# How to validate number of enter on input component react native

Tags: react-native

I wanted to create an input component that accept maximum number of enter/new line of 12, if user input 13th enter/new line. nothing will happen/change.

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like that:

```js
const MAX_NEWLINES = 12

const MyTextInput = (props) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      onChangeText={(newText) => {
        //if there is 'MAX_NEWLINES' lines, don't do anything
        if (newText && newText.split('\n').length > MAX_NEWLINES) return ;

        //else, store your new text
        setText(newText)
      }}
      multiline={true}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `maxLength` prop for TextInput component.

```
<TextInput maxLength={12} />
```

It will prevent more characters after the 12th character is entered.